# Installing SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2012 breaks SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2012

SSRS 2008 has been running fine for a long while.

We've installed SSRS 2012 onto the same server and it seemed to have broken SSRS 2008 sharepoint mode a bit.

All .rdl and .rsds files are no longer "associated" with the server. When you click on the report, it downloads these files instead of executing/displaying the reports.
(The icons are also changed to a "blank document" look). No settings have been changed. ie.
Allow management of content types? is Yes etc.

When you go to the server and go to Configuration Tools --> Reporting Services Configuration Manager, it no longer seem to recognise the Server Name (Invalid Namespace).

Any ideas on how to get it working again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are not using the same ports. The default port is 80. Have you changed this?

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143711.aspx